# Extracting strings from file with Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a file index.txt which contains PC name [say temp[0] etc.] and performance parameter [say 2.3 etc], arranged in tabular fashion as

```
PC  Memory  Processor  Bus  Performance .
```

i want a tcl file to extract string PC and Performance values only.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1):

You will want the `textutil::split` package from [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/).

```
package require textutil::split
set fid [open index.txt r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    lassign [textutil::split::splitx $line] pc memory processor bus performance
    puts "$pc  $performance"
}
```

If you don't want to use tcllib, you can do this:

```
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    set words [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
    if {[llength $words] == 7} {
        puts "[lindex $words 0]  [lindex $words 4]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Workaround. But i don't have access to this tcllib packages, can there be some other workaround?

Comment: @kunal They're _just plain Tcl code_; download and copy will work fine…

Comment: It looks like the `csv` package might also be relevant, if those are tabs that are being used to divide things up.

Comment: @DonalFellows  i tried with the workaround but just pc value is printed not performance

Comment: link to my index.txt file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_lSutatLFcpNGZ2MEpIMXJEaTg/edit?usp=sharing    i want temp* and corresponding number 2.3/2.1 for performance as output. Thanks in advance for the help